# Spring @Lookup method having String[] argument using full annotations configuration

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, spring-annotations

I have a JavaFX application and i want to do injection of a prototype scopped bean in a Singleton scopped bean using Lookup method and all my configuration is using javax.inject API

```
@Named
@Singleton
public abstract class DataModel {

    public ObservableList<Series<Number, Number>> observableList;

    public DataModel() {
        observableList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    }

    public void refresh(String[] selectedCountries) {
        observableList.clear();
        SeriesDataAdater seriesDataAdapter = getPopulationFirstCaseRelativeSeriesDataAdapter(selectedCountries);
        observableList.addAll(seriesDataAdapter.getSeriesList());
    }


    @Lookup()
    public abstract FirstCaseDateX_NewCasesPerPopulationY_SeriesDataAdapter getPopulationFirstCaseRelativeSeriesDataAdapter(String[] selectedCountries);
}


@Named
@Scope("prototype")
public class FirstCaseDateX_NewCasesPerPopulationY_SeriesDataAdapter extends SeriesDataAdater{

    @Inject
    public FirstCaseDateX_NewCasesPerPopulationY_SeriesDataAdapter(String[] selectedCountries, DataCache cache) {
        super(cache, selectedCountries);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Series<Number, Number>> getSeriesList() {
        ....
    }

    @Override
    public Series<Number, Number> getSeries(String country) {
        ....
    }

}
```

i have this exception :

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'firstCaseDateX_NewCasesPerPopulationY_SeriesDataAdapter' defined in
>   file
>   [D:\JAVA\workspaces\covid-19\covid19-unified-start-time-line-chart\target\classes\com\othmen\test\covid19\seriesdatasource\FirstCaseDateX_NewCasesPerPopulationY_SeriesDataAdapter.class]:
>   Could not resolve matching constructor (hint: specify index/type/name
>   arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)

i think he is not able to inject the argument selectedCountries because it is a simple type (String[]) but i dont know how to give him more informations (name or index) like he want.

i think i can solve this problem by creating a custom class as wrapper for my String[] parameter or by definning a FactoryBean for my String[] which will allow me to give him a Qualifier and the add @Qualifier in the prototype  constrcutor but is there an easier way to give him a Qualifier ?

Answer (score 0):

Move DataCache from constuctor to separate setter with @Autowired annotation. @Lookup should match constuctor parameters' types and parameters count, you can't use partial of definition.